# Import Spreadsheet - An unexpected error has occured. (Office 2016 / SharePoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, import, office-2016

I'm doing research as to why the Import Spreadsheet app in SharePoint 2013 (on prem) no longer works as I have Office 2016 installed on my Windows 7 computer using IE11.

[image]

the following message appears when I attempt to do so.

[image]

The only workaround I found so far is to approach this from excel 2016 and create a table and use the **Export table to SharePoint list** wizard found under the Design tab instead of importing it from the Import Spreadsheet app on SharePoint.

[image]

Any thoughts on how I might further troubleshoot this app would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more testing I found that this worked on another workstation and narrowed it down to my computer that had the issue.

long story short I ran `gpupdate /force` in command prompt or powershell to update my computers policy / security information. This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Recent update to Office 2016 broke the import function completely for me. On a machine with Office 2013 I see the same error as you but updating policies had no effect.

Comment: Did you try it in different browsers? (Edge / IE11 / other?)

Comment: IE10 and IE11 and compatibility view (IE9). Also using the dev tools emulation thingy.

Comment: This didn't solve my issue, but I did find a workaround here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211917/cannot-connect-to-the-server-at-this-time-youre-table-cannot-be-published

Answer (score 0):

Hope that below Cumulative Update from Microsoft should resolve the issue related to importing from Excel 2016.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2920678/march-8--2016--update-for-office-2016-kb2920678

Comment: Instead of directly pasting links you can quote important points and then add reference,

Answer (score 0):

This is because of permissions. The user who is trying to open the (.iqy) file should be also added in site or site collection. Try after adding the user. I faced the same issue and it helped :).