# Cannot connect to the server at this time, you're table cannot be published

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

I created a list in SharePoint Online, I'm using the url to the list but I receive this error when trying to export from excel.

URL example: `https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/lists/excel_test/allitems.aspx`

[image]

Comment: check this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/838703/you-receive-a-cannot-connect-to-server-at-this-time.-your-list-cannot-be-published-error-message-when-you-import-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-use-as-a-basis-for-a-new-list-in-windows-sharepoint-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out...

Excel creates the list for you. Add the URL to the SITE where you want to create a new list.

URL example: `https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/`

To update, you should have the ability to select from the existing list.